# how to handle "ctrl + s" event on chrome and ie .using jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I can use this code to handle <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> on firefox :

```
$(window).unbind('keypress').keypress(function(event) {
                    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey)) return true;
                    $('#save').click();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
```

but, it doesn't work on chrome or ie,

so what can i do  ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution about cross browser key event handler, Test done in IE FF and Chrome.

I'm struggling in it several days, please contact me if any question.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var currKey=0,e=e||event; 
    currKey=e.keyCode||e.which||e.charCode;  //do this handle FF and IE
    if (!( String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's' && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("put your code here")
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [this library](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/#).